# Como fazer script simples de include em html

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer um script simples para disponibilizar a  minha tela de login aos meus cliente .

- 'Exemplo' tenho um formulario simples que loga no meu sistema

  ```
        <form action="http://www.xx.com.br/logar.php">
        <input type="text" name="login">
        <input type="text" name="senha">
        <input type="submit" value="Logar">
        </form>
  ```

Queria uma forma simples de disponibilizar esse formulario para meus cliente incluírem em seus sites tipo um include mais que rode em html simples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos dizer que o domínio com o `JavaScript` com o formulário de login é `seusite.com`.

Crie um arquivo javascript: **`seusite.com/formulario.js`**

```
function loginMeuSite() {
    var divLoginSite = document.getElementById("divLoginSite");
    divLoginSite.innerHTML = '<form action="http://www.xx.com.br/logar.php"><input type="text" name="login"><input type="text" name="senha"><input type="submit" value="Logar"></form>';
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { loginMeuSite(); });
```

Peça à seus clientes para inserirem o seguinte javascript preferencialmente entre as tags `<head></head>`:

```
<script src="http://seusite.com/formulario.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

E peça para inserirem o `<div>` do formulário de login no **local** desejado onde o formulário de login deverá aparecer:

```
<div id="divLoginSite"></div>
```

**Exemplo**

**`sitedocliente.com/cliente.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Incluindo JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="http://seusite.com/formulario.js" type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <caption>Tabela 1</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="divLoginSite"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito resolveu meu problema.....

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de fazer isso, sugiro, pode ser através de um iframe ou fazendo um embed via javascript.

A maneira simplificada de fazer isso, é unindo iframe e embed, você teria que pedir para o cliente colocar o código no lugar que você deseja inserir o conteúdo para você fazer o insert da sua url contendo o código do formulário, exemplo:

```js
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>     
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');       
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);

   iframe.src = 'url-do-formulário';       
   iframe.width = 'largura-do-formulário'; // em pixels
   iframe.height = 'altura-do-formulário'; // em pixels
</script>
```

Comment: `IFRAME` já é considerado obsoleto por muitos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755795/are-iframes-html-obsolete

Comment: As respostas mais votadas no link que você citou dizem que isso é uma bobagem. Iframe ainda existe e é válido, só não precisa mais ser usado em tantas situações como antigamente. Mas incluir conteúdo de um site externo é o uso típico até hoje.

Comment: Claro que é utilizado ainda até hoje, como adsense, etc, mas acho que javascript e outras tecnologias que são compatíveis com praticamente todos os mobiles avançaram tanto que tornam outras obsoletas (iframe), porém funcionais.

Answer (score 0):

O modo mais simples que você pode fazer é criar um apontamento CNAME no site do seu cliente para determinada página, quando o cliente acessar a página de login dele através de um subdomínio por exemplo, o apontamento será para o seu sistema, sem vc precisar distribuir um iframe ou algo assim, que geraria um desgaste maior com manutenções futuras.

Segue um DNS RECORD de exemplo

```
NAME                 TYPE   VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
login.cliente.com.   CNAME  login.meusistema.com.
```

Comment: Nesse caso cada cliente incluiria o form por conta própria, e alteraria o action para o record criado? É essa a ideia?